# Production environment THIN is not loading data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, production-environment, thin, amazon-ami

When I'm trying to serve a ruby project (I'm migrating this project from another server where is working perfectly) with **thin** in production, I can't access to the site, however its working perfectly in development

```
$ thin start -e production
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

In another terminal:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
[deploy@host dir]$
```

But if I try with development environment, curl is showing me the content correctly.

The log/production.log doesnt show anything at all.

My versions:

ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p647 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v
Rails 4.2.1

thin -v
thin 1.6.3 codename Protein Powder

But if I create a new ruby project, **thin** is serving it with no issues:

```
curl http://localhost:3000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  body {
```

Any ideas about what configuration I'm missing? I precompiled all my assets (just in case). The project is working with **Passenger** in the previous server

Thanks

/Cris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the config.force_ssl parameter in config/environments/production.rb, it was in "true", but in the new server I didnt have the SSL configuration ready yet, so I changed it to false and it worked!

```
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false
```

I hope it helps!

Cheers